Problemas con reglas iptables entre dos interfaces virtuales vmware en Debian
Buen día
Que tal amigos, ando con un servidor DHCPD en Debian, el cual corre correctamente sobre una interface virtual ens38, asigna direccionamiento local sin problemas a un servidor HTTPD, hay comunicación en ambas direcciones.
Por otro lado tengo otra interface virtual ens33 en el Debian, que me da salida a internet, la configuración es la siguiente.
ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.140  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fed8:9415  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:d8:94:15  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 818  bytes 61259 (59.8 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 777  bytes 87592 (85.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens38: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.5.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.5.255
        inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fed8:941f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:d8:94:1f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3918  bytes 249710 (243.8 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 427  bytes 40506 (39.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

El problema que tengo, es que quiero que la interface ens38 tenga salida a internet a travez de la ens33, he aplicado la siguiente configuración pero no he logrado que las dos interfaces me hagan NAT adecuadamente, la puerta de enlace para mi lan 192.168.5.1 siempre me responde que no puede acceder al destino 8.8.8.8 cuando pruebas de ping.
root@DHCP:/# echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
root@DHCP:/# iptables -A INPUT -i ens33 -j ACCEPT
root@DHCP:/# iptables -A INPUT -i ens38 -j ACCEPT
root@DHCP:/# iptables -A FORWARD -i ens33 -j ACCEPT

No se si esto pueda servirles, he puesto un snifer en la interface ens38 de la LAN y veo continuamente trafico con estas lineas, como si fuera un problema con la MAC.
19:23:45.484793 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.5.1 tell 192.168.5.128, length 46
19:23:46.519517 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.5.1 tell 192.168.5.128, length 46
19:23:47.537264 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.5.1 tell 192.168.5.128, length 46
19:23:48.561292 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.5.1 tell 192.168.5.128, length 46

Que podra estar mal?

veo que no indicas en ningun momento que el forward es nat.
Esta es la config que yo aplicaría.
# Permitir tráfico de entrada en ambas interfaces
iptables -A INPUT -i ens33 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i ens38 -j ACCEPT

# Permitir el reenvío entre las interfaces
iptables -A FORWARD -i ens38 -o ens33 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i ens33 -o ens38 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Hacer NAT para el tráfico saliente por ens33
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens33 -j MASQUERADE

Puedes verificar el funcionamiento activando los logs de iptables
iptables -A FORWARD -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables-FORWARD: " --log-level 4


Que tal amigo, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, con esto me doy cuenta que el problema no es iptables, seguia siendo un problema de arp, asi que asigne la ip 192.168.6.1 en la ens38 del servidor del dhcpd, y quite la 192.168.6.2, de esta forma pude tener salida a internet, el problema era que el servidor httpd no reconocia la mac de 192.168.6.1, pero si de 192.168.6.2, por eso no salia internet, asi que mejor le cambie la ip en el servidor con el gateway, ahora tengo salida a internet sin problemas, muchas gracias nuevamente.
